# when i fetch data i can see that state is set but when i call data from state it's showing object undefined

Tags: react-native, expo, setstate

This is my code when i am using this.state.user.anything its just showing me it's empty.
Any helps will be appreciated. thank you for your time.

i am not getting any leads to solve it so.

```
export default class details extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userData: null,
      user: null,
    };
    this.getUsers();
  }
  getUsers = async () => {
    let urlUsers = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
    let req = await fetch(urlUsers);
    let res = await req.json();
    this.setState({
      userData: res,
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.userData[i].id == this.props.route.params.id) {
        await this.setState({
          user: {
            name: this.state.userData[i].name,
            uid: this.state.userData[i].id,
            phone: this.state.userData[i].phone,
            email: this.state.userData[i].email,
            website: this.state.userData[i].website,
            username: this.state.userData[i].username,
          },
        });
      }
    }
    console.log(this.state.user);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>User Id : {this.state.user.uid}</Text>
        <Text>Name : {this.state.user.name}</Text>
        <Text>email : {this.state.user.email}</Text>
        <Text>phone : {this.state.user.phone}</Text>
        <Text>Website : {this.state.user.website}</Text>
        <Text>username : {this.state.user.username}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

this is how it's snowing me error[image]

Comment: Render method is called immediately after constructor, your getUsers method is async by that time user is null when accessed in the render method. Either initialize user as an empty object in the constructor or use checks in the render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured later I am not sure exactly if that was correct reason.

I tried to define each states separately, instead assigning whole json object to the state and it worked.

```
export default class details extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userData: null,
      uid: null,
      name: null,
      phone: null,
      email: null,
      website: null,
      username: null,
    };
    this.getUsers();
  }
  getUsers = async () => {
    let urlUsers = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
    let req = await fetch(urlUsers);
    let res = await req.json();
    this.setState({
      userData: res,
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.userData[i].id == this.props.route.params.id) {
        await this.setState({
          name: this.state.userData[i].name,
          uid: this.state.userData[i].id,
          phone: this.state.userData[i].phone,
          email: this.state.userData[i].email,
          website: this.state.userData[i].website,
          username: this.state.userData[i].username,
        });
      }
    }
  };
```

thank everyone for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is that it is taking time to get user data and reset the state again and the `render` method called immediately so it crashes. This might help

```
render() {
    return this.state.user ? (
      <View>
        <Text>User Id : {this.state.user.uid}</Text>
        <Text>Name : {this.state.user.name}</Text>
        <Text>email : {this.state.user.email}</Text>
        <Text>phone : {this.state.user.phone}</Text>
        <Text>Website : {this.state.user.website}</Text>
        <Text>username : {this.state.user.username}</Text>
      </View>
    ) : null;
  }
```